# Create columns based on the same column name with different value

Tags: php, mysql, database, excel, metadata

I have a table:

[image: Meta table]

As above image shows there are many other meta_appl_id's.

Now I want to run an SQL query so that will create columns based on the value of "meta_value". I tried:

```
    SELECT * ,
if (`meta_value` = 'physically challenged' , 'yes', '') as PH,
if (`meta_value` = 'kannada medium' , 'yes', '') as Kannada,
if (`meta_value` = 'rural' , 'yes', '') as rural,
if (`meta_value` = 'woman' , 'yes', '') as woman 
FROM `applicant_meta` WHERE `meta_value` = 'physically challenged' or `meta_value` = 'woman' group by meta_appl_id;
```

but could not get the needed output, only one column value as shown:

[image: Output]

Actually in row meta_appl_id 59 it have to show Ph - yes, rural - yes and woman yes but its only showing in woman (because it is last if statement in query).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT meta_appl_id, if(PH= 0, 'no', 'yes'), if(WOMAN= 0, 'no', 'yes')
FROM (
    SELECT meta_appl_id
        , (select count(1) FROM applicant_meta as innertab where UPPER(innertab.meta_appl_id) = UPPER(aa.meta_appl_id) and UPPER(meta_value)=UPPER('physically challenged')) as PH
        , (select count(1) FROM applicant_meta as innertab where innertab.meta_appl_id = aa.meta_appl_id and UPPER(meta_value)='WOMAN') as WOMAN
    FROM applicant_meta as aa
    GROUP BY meta_appl_id
) as bb;
```

Please add other possible columns according to need. I have shown 2 columns here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but its not working. it is giving answer as above image.

Comment: Can you please check your table data then, May be it is case-sensitivity or Unwanted-spaces issue. My solution needs UPPER case - 'PH' and 'WOMAN'. Just copy paste should work for these 2 columns at least.